# Spectrum of a matrix operator on $L^2$ product space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I am interested in a spectrum of a simple operator, effectively given by a matrix $A$, acting on a space $U$ that is $n$-th power of same base space V, $U = \underbrace{V \times \dots \times V}_{n\ \text{times}}$. Lets take $U = V \times V$, $V = L^2$ and
\begin{align}
&A = \begin{bmatrix} a &b \\ b &d \end{bmatrix} \quad \quad a,b,d \in \mathbb R, \\
&A \begin{pmatrix} f_1 \\ f_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a f_1 + b f_2 \\ b f_1 + d f_2 \end{pmatrix} \quad \quad \forall \begin{pmatrix} f_1 \\ f_2 \end{pmatrix} \in U.
\end{align}
I would like to show that the spectrum of $A: U \to U$ is the same as the spectrum of $A: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

My idea is to go from the definition and check condition under which $A - \lambda I$ is not onto and not one-to-one. Checking the one-to-one property seems easy since that means solving a linear system
$$
(A - \lambda I) v = 0 \quad v \in U
$$
which can be done e. g. by Gauss elimination method and gives the same conditions on $\lambda$ being the root of the characteristic polynomial as in the linear algebraic case.
I have trouble showing the condition for $A-\lambda I$ being no onto. This means that the system
$$
(A-\lambda I) x = b
$$
has a solution for all $b \in U$.
The standard argument from linear algebra is that a matrix is onto when its columns are linearly independent does not translate well here. If we denote the columns of $A-\lambda I$ as $c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $x = (x_1, x_2)$, then the system can be rewritten as
\begin{align}
x_1 c_1 + x_2 c_2 = b.
\end{align}
The trouble with this is that $x_1, x_2$ that play the role of coefficient in the linear algebra case are now elements of $V$ and not $\mathbb R$ so this approach seem to lead nowhere. I think that the condition of $c_1, c_2$ being linearly independent is necessary and sufficient but I am not able to find the right argument or framework which would make this problem trivial. (The space $U$ looks a bit like $\mathbb{R}^2 \otimes V$ but I did not find any helpful reference for that.) I would be grateful for any direction or a suitable book/paper to follow.

Comment: You're treating $V$ as the coefficients, but $V$ is not a field, so $U$ is not a vector space over $V$. Your $f_1,f_2$ are like the $i,j$ vectors, so they're fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A-\lambda I\in\Bbb R^{2\times 2}$ is either invertible, whence $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ will act as the (bounded) inverse of $(A-\lambda I):V\times V\to V\times V$,
or, its kernel is nontrivial, whence $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, and as you correctly deduced, the action of $A-\lambda I$ on $V\times V$ is not injective either.

Answer (score 1):

The above interpretation of a $2\times 2$ matrix as an operator on $V\times V$ may be seen as an isomorphism from $M_2(\mathbb C)$ to a closed unital *-subalgebra of operators on $V\times V$.

By the spectral permanence theorem an element of such a sub-algebra is invertible relative to the sub-algebra iff it is invertible as an operator.

Therefore the spectrum of any given matrix coincides with the spectrum of the corresponding operator.

Comment: This sounds nice. Do you have a tip for a nice reference for the spectral permanence?

Comment: Check Theorem 4.8 in Williams  "Lecture notes on the spectral Theorem" https://math.dartmouth.edu/~dana/bookspapers/ln-spec-thm.pdf

Comment: @Ruy Does those results still valid also for the essential spectrum ?

Comment: @SAKLY, no they don't.  In finite dimensions the essential spectrum of an operator is the empty set (since every operator is compact, everything is invertible modulo compacts!!), but not so in infinite dimensions .  For example, the $2\times2$ identity matrix is such an operator, but if $V$ is infinite dimensional then the corresponding operator on $V\times V$ is the identity there and its essential spectrum is $\{1\}$.